# How can I kill a wxpython app with an accelerator key when topframe does not have focus?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

**[PROBLEM]**
I want to close via an accelerator key a wxpython app when topframe does not have focus.
If topframe has focus and I press 'F2' key then the app is closed, otherwise nothing is happening.

**[CODE]**

```
import wx 
app = wx.App(False) 
top = wx.Frame(None, title=" test")
def showMsg(event):
        wx.MessageBox("test", "ERROR")



def killApp(event):
        top.SetFocus()
        event.Skip()
        top.Destroy()


sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()
RUN_ID = wx.NewId()
top.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, killApp, id=RUN_ID)
accel_tbl = wx.AcceleratorTable([(wx.ACCEL_NORMAL,  wx.WXK_F2, RUN_ID ),

                                 ])
top.SetAcceleratorTable(accel_tbl)
cancelButton = wx.Button(top, -1, "Cancel", (160,100), size=(45, -1))
sizer.Add(cancelButton,(1,27),(1,1),wx.EXPAND)
top.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, showMsg, cancelButton)
top.SetSizer(sizer)  
top.Show(True)     # Show the frame.
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Windows, there is a library called `pyhook` (http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyhook/files/pyhook/) 
which provides a global hook for python process.

I used it in the past for a pyGTK app and it worked ok but often pyhook stop working after some time. So, it may not be so stable (or just my code was bad). It should be easy to mix with wx.

Answer (score 0):

Accelerator keys will only work in your program. If some other program, like Notepad or Eclipse has focus, then they will be receiving the key events instead of your program.

If you are trying to intercept key events before they reach an application, then that is usually handled on the OS level. That is typically not recommended as it can interfere with other programs normal behavior.

Comment: I see your point. That's why I tried to force focus on frame ("top.SetFocus()"). Once topFrame has focus I guess the app will be destroyed.

Comment: If you have a sub-window of your application that has the focus, then you should be able to use the accelerator